# iOS application Metadata Rejected

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I upload my app to appstore. Today app i got app rejected with metadata. They put reason with 3.3: Apps with descriptions not relevant to the application content and functionality will be rejected. We found that the screenshots for your app do not reflect the app in use. This does not give the user an accurate understanding of what the app does or how it behaves. It means my description is not match to app?

Comment: Does anyone give proper answer?

Comment: Have you got the solution.

Comment: Yes...Is your application rejected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your description is not matching to your app functionality. So you should need to change your  application description and as well as Your Screenshot. Because Your screenshot is not show your  App functionality.

Comment: The screenshot is what im using inside my app. I took screenshot from app. Then i used for review. What is the issue of this.

Comment: You should to show all of your app functionality in screenshot.

Comment: I used IAP products. two videos free all other payable. I have 10 buttons for 10 videos in same page. My app have only one page. One image having 10 buttons. That's all. Here what im going to change

Comment: You need to mention more screenshot. when u click on video then take a screenshot and also take IAP screenshot etc and then try.

Comment: Previously i didn't use what you mentioned, but my app accepted.

Answer (score 0):

my app rejected.solve is simple . Only put your app's screenshot to itunesconnect . Your screenshot have to show your application screen.